# Converting uptimeMillis to elapsedRealTimeNanos

Tags: android, time

Is it possible to convert `SystemClock.uptimeMillis` to `SystemClock.elapsedRealTimeNanos`?

The reason I'd like to do this is that events use `uptimeMillis`, but the GPS uses `elapsedRealTimeNanos`, and I'd like to connect these two.

The only solution I see is that in the event listener, I query both times, calculate the difference, and apply this difference to the time of the event.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Isn't it  just a convertsion from `millis` to `nanos`?

Comment: @NiVeR: that's a part of it, but it is not the main problem, it's just a multiplication by 1000000. The problem is that these two clocks run in a different manner (`uptimeMillis` stops when the system is sleeping, while `elapsedRealTimeNanos` doesn't).